# cannot be declared in scope (among other errors)

Tags: c#, string, variables, scope

hello im new to programing with c# and i wanted to re-create an old proyect i made in scratch but with c#

[image: the scratch code]

but i have several problems with the code i wrote.

```
int qny = 4;
int ADD = 1;
int B = 1;
string C = " ";
for (int i = 0; i < qny; i++) ;
{
    int R = qny + ADD;
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) ;
    {
        string C = string.Join(C, B);
    }
    int qny = qny - 1;
    int B = B + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(C);
```

the main problem is that i cant use the variables "qny","B" and "C" inside the "for". the only one that doesnt show an error message is the "ADD" variable

its suposed to write numbers like this

| qny | result |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 112 |
| 3 | 111223 |
| 4 | 1111222334 |

errors:

```
Error   CS0841  Cannot use local variable 'qny' before it is declared. A variable must be declared before it is used.

Error   CS0136  A local variable named 'C' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'C', which is already used in a 'parent or current/child' scope to denote something else

Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'C'


Error   CS0841  Cannot use local variable 'B' before it is declared.


Error   CS0136  A local variable named 'qny' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'qny', which is already used in a 'parent or current/child' scope to denote something else


Error   CS0136  A local variable named 'B' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'B', which is already used in a 'parent or current/child' scope to denote something else
```

Comment: Second `for` uses `i` as well for the loop, that won't work, use another name or remove `int` after `for`.

Comment: that didnt show in the errors list. i did change it to test but still  the same problem

Comment: please show all the code, please show the complete error message(s)

Comment: @user20618074 also check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops end with a semicolon, which ends the loop. The following code blocks are not treated as part of the loop body because of that. Additionally as aybe mentioned you use i for both loops which will update the same variable.

EDIT: As mentioned below you also shouldn't redeclare the variable C as it won't update the variable C at the top, same reason as to why you don't want to use i for both loops.

EDIT: Code below still has redeclared variables, check author's answer for updated code.

I suggest changing it to this:

```
int qny = 4;
int ADD = 1;
int B = 1;
string C = " ";
for (int i = 0; i < qny; i++)
{
    int R = qny + ADD;
    for (int j = 0; j < R; j++)
    {
        C = string.Join(C, B);
    }
    int qny = qny - 1;
    int B = B + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(C);
```

To avoid such errors in the future I would recommend checking out some tutorials on the basics of C#. I wish you good luck on your coding journey!

Comment: also probably dont want to redeclare C inside the loop

Comment: You're right totally missed that.

Comment: its better now, i had 8 error messages before, but now i have 6 still. i can send you the whole error list but its in spanish

Comment: The errors should all have error codes you can look up in the documentation. Most of the time they will accurately describe what is wrong with your code. otherwise updating your question with more of your code might help us understand what is wrong.

Comment: that is the whole code. im new so i wanted to make something simple for my first aproach. i also uploadated the error list and the error codes after your fix

Comment: In C# you can only write code like this in functions which in turn are members of classes. Currently the compiler expects a class definition while you are writing method code. I recommend reading up on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people that helped me. As someone suggested, I’ll check out some tutorials. The final code looks like this:

```
int qny = 4;
int ADD = 1;
int B = 1;
string C = " ";
for (int i = 0; i < qny; i++)
{
    int R = qny + ADD;
    for (int j = 0; j < R; j++)
    {
        C = string.Join(C, B);
    }
    qny = qny - 1;
    B = B + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(C);
```